# Who is this "other" Wyatt?

Tags: character, westworld-tv

During the course of season one of *Westworld*, we learn that Dr. Ford has decided to let Arnold's legacy live with the intent of allowing the hosts to become conscious by setting up a prequel narrative into 'Journey into Night', in which Dolores relives memories of a time when she first met William, and in which past Dolores was also remembering events from an even further past, leading to the incident with herself killing Arnold. As such, Ford gives the darker persona of Dolores it's own name, Wyatt, in which he also then manifests into Teddy's backstory and current story, in attempts to fully awaken Dolores.

[image: Teddy's Wyatt]

But Teddy remembers Wyatt looking differently, as Ford probably intentionally disguised Dolores in Teddy's *new memories for this to work, but my question is, who was the man/host used [in image] in Dolores' place? Is he of any consequence or another character viewers have seen elsewhere?